# How to have mongodb (pymongo) return _id as key value pair in response instead of object structure?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am using pymongo with flask.
I my use case, I can have mongodb's document _id either as integer (migrated data from relational store) or the monogo's ObjectId() (generated).

In get response I get something like this in each case respectively:

**1st case (with integer id):**

```
{
    "_id": 123456,
     "name": "something.."
}
```

**2nd case with ObjectId()**

```
{
    "_id":
        {
           "$oid": "55f5efc60640fd09620c109c"
        },
     "name": "something.."
}
```

I want to have uniform structure in both the cases - 
So I would like the 2nd case to be like -

```
{
    "_id": "55f5efc60640fd09620c109c",
     "name": "something.."
}
```

How to achieve this? **Other than iterating through each results and replacing the values?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution to my problem, sharing so can help others.

In mongo there is no schema so you can have value of _id as anything (integer/object/string, as in my case).

In python, I did this to have command key-value pair structure:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
new_doc = db.collection.insert({'_id': str(ObjectId())})  // This won't create additional _id field in your document.
```

Do find like:

```
doc = db.collections.find_one({'_id': "12-char-mongodb-type-id"})
doc = db.collections.find_one({'_id': 12345})
```