# How to return _id as ObjectId string without looping the whole collection?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am having problems with `stringify _id`.

After querying the collection with `mongo.db.some_collection.find()`, I got something like the following:

```
 [{
    "_id":
        {
           "$oid": "581c0967e14c8b2118a31758"
        },
     "name": "something"
 },
 {
    "_id":
        {
           "$oid": "581c50aae14c8b214a3d2231"
        },
     "name": "something else"
 }]
```

I would like the API response to be something as simple as the following to make things easier for the front end devs. They don't want to do something like `item._id.$oid` to get the actual id.

```
 [{
    "_id": "581c0967e14c8b2118a31758",
    "name": "something"
 },
 {
    "_id": "581c50aae14c8b214a3d2231",
    "name": "something else"
 }]
```

I don't want to loop over all the results and manipulate every item to get what I want. Is there a way (a function?) to convert `_id` without looping?

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555649/how-to-have-mongodb-pymongo-return-id-as-key-value-pair-in-response-instead-o), but the suggestion is to manipulate `_id` when insert. I actually don't mind it when inserting.

Comment: After getting result,try this,var v= JSON.stringifi(result);JSON.parsr(v)

Comment: @Parshuram Isn't JSON.stringify() a JS method? I am using python. Plus, the point is, I don't want to loop the result. I wanna get the `_id` as string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the project stage in the aggregation pipeine to reshape the fields, will return you the expected output.:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $project: 
        {
            name: 1,
            _id: '$_id.oid'
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the way to go. But the collection's `_id` field is looking like: `"_id" : ObjectId("581c0967e14c8b2118a31758") ` ( `_id.$oid` is the final result I got after jsonify). I couldn't figure out the way to covert this ObjectId to string in the projection specification. Help needed.

Comment: What is your mongoDB version??

Comment: @Parshuram v3.2.9